# Is Content-Type mandatory in HTTP post request?

Tags: http, post

Is the field:

> Content-Type

mandatory when I perform an HTTP request?

Comment: Consider that if you don't send one, the other side will have no idea how to interpret the payload.

Comment: Uhm, no. The default is "application/octet-stream", which makes sense. By the end of the day, the payload is nothing but bytes and will always be bytes. The _presence_ of a content type provides an alternative method how those bytes can be decoded into a different representation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory. Per the [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

That said, it's obviously going to be hard for the server to accurately interpret the data you're sending if you omit the Content-Type header, so it's not recommended to do so.

Answer (score 10):

From the [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html)

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
>   only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
>   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
>   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
>   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
>   treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

So it is adviced to do, not mandatory. But the recipient might guess the content-type if none is given.

Comment: "But the client..." You mean "but the server..." else it makes no sense ;-)

Comment: I doubt it [The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) but I'll use recipient to avoid confusion.