# Android HttpURLConnection empty post

Tags: java, android

I have a code that sends a request with post parameters. However, when I check on server, the post array is empty. I've tried everything I found in internet, but nothing helped.What is an wrong here?

```
    String url = "http://exifeed.com/api.php";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    String urlParameters = "ApiKey=xxx";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    con.connect();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(response.toString()));
```

Code on server

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

The output result is

> Array()Array()

P.S. I added www. before domain name and it suddenly worked. I guess it was because I had redirect in .htaccess file on server. Thanks everyone anyway.

Comment: because you don't give a content type, you need to use `file_get_contents('php://input');` to access the content of the post body.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing the `Content-Type` header. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860815/2657100). You can set a header this way:

```java
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: I tried setting Content-Type parameter, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

sorry man i can't reply on prev post ..

i tried this locally using post-man:

PHP Script :

.........
POST request :
with parameters : 
tag : register
name : murad
email : m@m.com
password : 123

.......
and this is the output:
Array ( [tag] => register [name] => murad [email] => m@m.com [password] => 123 ) Array ( )
......

please check the php version u have coz print_r as the doc say for : (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)